# Conditional distribution given density function

Tags: probability, integration, improper-integrals, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with joint density $f_{X,Y}(x, y)$ = \begin{cases}
    \frac{21x^4(1-y)^5e^{\frac{-x}{y}}}{y^2} & \text{if} \ x>0, 0< y < 1,  \\
    \ 0 & \text{otherwise } \\ 
\end{cases}

What is the conditional distribution $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$?

What I've tried was:

$$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)} = \frac{\frac{21x^4(1-y)^5e^{\frac{-x}{y}}}{y^2}}{\int_0^\infty \frac{21x^4(1-y)^5e^{\frac{-x}{y}}}{y^2}dx} \\$$

But I find the integration of $f_Y(y)$ very difficult to solve. I've tried to integrate by parts but it keeps resulting in messy integrals. I would like to know if there is another way less focused on integral solving to find $f_Y(y)$ and tehre fore the conditional distribution of X given Y.

Comment: Integrating by parts is definitely a reasonable way to go. It might look a little cleaner if you substitute $x=uy$ first and eliminate any common factors from both the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the [gamma function definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$$\Gamma(z) = \int_{t=0}^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t} \, dt \tag{1}$$ from which we can evaluate the desired marginal density of $Y$ after a substitution of the form $x = yt$, $dx = y \, dt$:

$$\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{21(1-y)^5}{y^2} \int_{x=0}^\infty x^4 e^{-x/y} \, dx \\
&= \frac{21(1-y)^5}{y^2} \int_{t=0}^\infty y^4 t^4 e^{-t} y \, dt \\
&= 21y^3(1-y)^5 \int_{t=0}^\infty t^4 e^{-t} \, dt \\
&= 21 y^3(1-y)^5 \Gamma(5) \\
&= 504 y^3(1-y)^5.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the resemble between $f_Y(y)$ and the gamma density function but didn't know how to proceed from there. How come this substitution insight comes to solve this types of problems?